# Hibernate Cascade DELETE OneToMany does not work. Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class Webtoon that contains a list of Episode. It is a one direction relation.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name= "list_of_episodes")
List<Episode> listOfEpisodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my Unit test, I created a Webtoon object, then added an episode in the list listOfEpisodes.
When I try to delete the Episode using the Episode repository

```
this.episodeRepo.delete(episode);
```

I got the error :

> violation de contrainte: "FK50GHKTDAXMN68TBU6KAYVUX9S:
>   PUBLIC.LIST_OF_EPISODES FOREIGN KEY(LIST_OF_EPISODES_ID) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.EPISODE(ID) (3)"
>       Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK50GHKTDAXMN68TBU6KAYVUX9S: PUBLIC.LIST_OF_EPISODES FOREIGN
>   KEY(LIST_OF_EPISODES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EPISODE(ID) (3)"; SQL
>   statement:
>       delete from episode where id=? [23503-200]

Why hibernate can't remove this object and update the list in Webtoon class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change FetchType from EAGER to LAZY

Answer (score 0):

Referential integrity is a property of data stating that all its references are valid. In the context of relational databases, it requires that if a value of one attribute (column) of a relation (table) references a value of another attribute (either in the same or a different relation), then the referenced value must exist.

From the error **PUBLIC.LIST_OF_EPISODES FOREIGN KEY(LIST_OF_EPISODES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EPISODE(ID)** you can clearly see that PUBLIC.EPISODE(ID) is referenced as a foreign key in PUBLIC.LIST_OF_EPISODES table so you cannot delete a parent unless you delete a child element.

Try using @JoinColumn instead of using @CollectionTable(name= "list_of_episodes")

Answer (score 0):

To correct this issue, I first changed the uni-directional relation to bi-directional.
In Webtoon I have :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="webtoon", orphanRemoval = true)
@CollectionTable(name= "list_of_episodes")
List<Episode> listOfEpisodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

In Episode, I added a webtoon attribute

```
@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="webtoon_id")
Webtoon webtoon;
```

Because, it is lazy...I could not get the list as if I'm using eager, so I added a join select in my repository. And also when I delete, I have the cascade delete.